# Repeat a range of a number of times

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sequence, spreadsheet, repeat

I'm trying to repeat something like this for every day of the year.
It could start at anytime, for example, like below:

01/01/2020  06:00:00
01/01/2020  07:00:00
....    ....    ...
Then...
01/01/2020  20:00:00
02/01/2020  06:00:00
02/01/2020  07:00:00
....    ....    ...
Then...
02/01/2020  20:00:00
03/01/2020  06:00:00
03/01/2020  07:00:00

I tried the following link, but this only worked on texts.  [Repeat a range a number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74353713/repeat-a-range-a-number-of-times?newreg=19dee519cbc246d8a2c5150a0fd83832)

Another one I've tried is this, but I cannot set the start/end time: [Repeat date sequence in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72785423/repeat-date-sequence-in-excel)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You time doesn't seems sequential?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it! It is one hour incremental from 6am to 8pm @Harun24hr

Comment: So start on `01/01/2020 06:00:00` then increment 1 hour? But how it is `01/01/2020 20:00:00`? Explain in brief in post.

Comment: @Harun24hr 8pm = 20:00:00. OP wants 6am-8pm, so their desired results is appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The below formula takes a SEQUENCE of every single hour, then filters it down to only the time ranges you need (in this case between `TIME(6,0,0)` and `TIME(20,0,0)`, so 6:00 to 20:00).

```
=LET(
AllHours, SEQUENCE(365*24, 1, DATE(2022, 1, 1), TIME(1,0,0)),
IsCorrectTime, BYROW(AllHours,LAMBDA(row,AND(MOD(row, 1)>=TIME(6,0,0),MOD(row,1)<=TIME(20,0,0)))),
FILTER(AllHours, IsCorrectTime)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you got Excel 365 use @SpencerBarnes with no doubt, but in case you got and older version of Excel you may do:

A1 = 01/01/2020 06:00:00

A2 = `=IF(HOUR(A1)=20;INT(A1)+1+1/4;A1+1/24)`

The main disavantadge of this solution is that you need manually to drag until last day of year... so if you can use @SpencerBarnes use it.

Comment: Thank you! I get the "There's a problem with this formula." error when I put the A2 formula in. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Sophia My argument separator is the semicolon `;` probably your argument separator is the comma `,`

Answer (score 1):

### Repeat/Increment Date Time In Column

```
=LET(Data,A2:A4,Repeats,C1,Start,C2,
    rs,ROWS(Data),s,Start-1,Seq,SEQUENCE(rs*Repeats-s,,s),
INDEX(Data,MOD(Seq,rs)+1)+INT(Seq/rs))
```

[image]